Populate Assignment group based on service offering and location in servicenow
I want to update the assignment group to a particular assignment group when the condition fulfills on RITM ie. service offering is xyz and location is abc, then it should update.
For example, there is one catalog item that is being raised by GETit and RITM is generated with an assignment group. I want to update that value when the matching conditions are fulfilled.
I tried using assignment rules but again it doesnt work if the field has already a value and in my case assignment group already has a value, we just need to update it.
Can someone please help me here.
I tried using assignment rules but again it doesnt work if the field has already a value and in my case assignment group already has a value, we just need to update it.

What’s setting the assignment group in the first place already? If it’s a workflow, then change the logic in the workflow to match your criteria, if it’s an assignment rule, then give your new rule a lower order so it takes precedence
